# Are these the only gauge-invariant functions of $A_\mu$?

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, yang-mills, wilson-loop

I know off course that $F_{\mu\nu}$ is a gauge invariant function of $A_\mu$ in the abelian case. Also we have $\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu} F_{\alpha\beta}F_{\mu\nu}$ in that case.

Are there any other functions? Perhaps one that cannot be built up from $F_{\mu\nu}$.

In the Non-abelian case I know that $tr F_{\mu\nu}^2$ is gauge invariant. Other examples are (since $\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu} F_{\alpha\beta}=\tilde F^{\mu\nu}$ is gauge covariant) : $tr \tilde F_{\mu\nu}^2$ $tr F_{\mu\nu}\tilde F^{\mu\nu}$.

The same question: Any other function of $A_\mu$? Perhaps one that cannot be built up from $F_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: Also, Wilson lines (which are non-local though).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I know that. But I want to understand what Peskin said "In fact, all gauge-invariant functions of $A^\mu$ can be thought of
as combinations of Wilson loops for various choices of the path P" In his book he sows how to get the $F^{\mu\nu}$, but what about other functions?

Answer (score 3):

There is a huge family of gauge-invariant operators called *Wilson lines*, which are of central interest to lattice QCD and holography.

Given a path $\gamma$ in spacetime, a Wilson line $W_{\gamma}$ is a gauge-invariant operator defined as

$$W_{\gamma}\equiv\text{P}\,\exp\left\{-i\int_{\gamma}A_{\mu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}\right\},$$

where $\text{P}\,\exp$ is the path ordered exponential (defined in the same way as the time ordered exponential defined in basic perturbation theory). Wilson lines, unlike the operators you listed above, are non-local.

In the abelian case, note that, due to Stoke's theorem, if $\gamma$ is closed then

$$W_{\gamma}\equiv\exp\left\{-i\oint_{\gamma}A\right\}=\exp\left\{-i\int_{\Sigma}F\right\},$$

where $\Sigma$ is any surface with $\partial\Sigma=\gamma$ (note that I have used the notation of differential forms). Thus, for a Wilson line over a sufficiently tight loop, we have

$$W_{\gamma}\approx 1-iS[\gamma]F,$$

where we have approximated $F$ as roughly constant along the loop, and $S[\gamma]$ is the minimal area of a surface whose boundary is $\gamma$. Thus, for small loops, Wilson lines can produce local gauge-invariant operators.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Such an exponential was used by P. Dirac in his gauge-invariant formulation of QED.

Comment: Thank you, in the case of local functions, Is not any other that cannot be built up from $F_{\mu\nu}$? Concerning of the production of local gauge-invariants from Wilson loops I have read on page 492 of Peskin and Schroeder: "Conversely, since (almost) all gauge-
invariant functions of $A^\mu$ can be built up from $F^{\mu\nu}$, this expression gives..." The "ALMOST" is my uncertainty.

Comment: I mean, How I can be sure that you actually can get all the local gauge invariants. You show how I can get $F$, but if there are any other gauge invariant?